# How to get the balance of a contract using Ether.js library

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, react

When I am using `(await provider.getBalance(contractAddress)).toNumber()` I am getting a balance of zero. I have sent 1 Ether to the smart contract prior to this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am no JavaScript expert, but I think the problem is that you are using .toNumber() on a promise (since the .toNumber() would run instantly and not wait for the promise to return), which will be undefined (or 0 I guess?)

I think this would work instead:

```
numStr = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);
number = parseInt(numStr);
```

Where `number` will be your balance as an integer, I think in wei, so you should expect ```number = 1000000000000000000````

If you want it in ether, you could do

```
numStr = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);
wei = parseInt(numStr);
ether = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, "ether");
```

Where `ether` should be 1 obviously

Answer (score 0):

EthersJS stores balance in Wei as an object of [BigNumber class](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/). `toNumber()` tries to cast input, in your case, to Integer, which is not enough to hold 1 ETH represented in Wei. Many operations in Ethereum operate on numbers that are outside the range of safe values to use in JavaScript.

1ETH = 1000000000000000000 WEI (vs a MAX_SAFE_INTEGER of 9007199254740991, see below)

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
// Expected output: 9007199254740991
```

If you try to simply display the balance, you can cast it to `String`:

```
(await provider.getBalance(contractAddress)).toString()
```

will return `1000000000000000000`

A *BigNumber* is an object which safely allows mathematical operations on numbers of any magnitude. Here is the list of common [methods](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--methods) to manipulate [BigNumber class](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber)